# Android Java, get data of Object Array inside Object Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, dimensions

I can put and get out Integer Array data inside Object Array easily:

```
Object[] ObjArr=new Object[]{1,"alo",3,new int[]{9,8,7} };
int[] out=ObjArr[3];
```

But it was imposible with Object Array:

```
Object[] ObjArr=new Object[]{1,"alo",3,new Object[]{9,"elo",7} };
Object[] out=ObjArr[3];
```

If I use 2 dimensions array Object[][], all element must be Object Array type. But I need multiple variable type. How to solve this?
That Object Array inside Object Array turned to Object, I got number 5 when try toString(), can I link this id to the real data (I think that it's hashcode and imposible to get the data I wanted)

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a `List`?

Comment: Using Object[] is much more faster and input writing less in this case, because I'm doing Input Flexible Multitype Variable (text, number,  array of double, runnable...) in array and contain child structure similar to it self (It's going to infinity dimension array, free and fast). However, I have changed to other way (build a new class), It's work ok.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet shouldn't compile either :)

You need a *cast*. It basically tells the compiler that you are certain that this thing (`ObjArr[3]`) is of this type (`Object[]`) and that the program will crash if it isn't.

```
Object[] out=(Object[])ObjArr[3]; // this will crash if ObjArr[3] is something else, like an int
```

If `ObjArr[3]` not being an `Object[]` is not fatal to your situation (you can handle this case), you can do a check before casting:

```
if (ObjArr[3] instanceof Object[]) {
    Object[] out = (Object[])ObjArr[3];
    // continue with "out"
} else {
    // ObjArr[3] is not an Object[]. Handle this situation
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before.  ObjArr[3] was still Object, not Object[]. So, it's always return false when trying "instanceof Object[]". However, thanks.